# Server-side JavaScript session and logging pages

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm trying to build a logging page before a landing page that I want to "protect".

Is it possible to create session on the server in order to build a logged microsite?

Comment: Have you checked to see if the security settings in the page properties will work for what you need?

Comment: I mena like variable session to control when user is logged...

Comment: You'd have to roll this yourself, but you can use the response object to set session cookies (no expiry date) using SSJS. See the SetCookie function:

http://bit.ly/2leeIXl

You could write some encrypted or obfuscated value in the cookie value that would allow you to validate that to cookie is good and the user is logged in using the GetCookieValue function:

http://bit.ly/2ljzKkc

Comment: @MrViSiOn Glad to hear it :)

Comment: With classic landing pages there is also a feature called [System Authenticated Redirection](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/microsites/landing_pages/create_a_landing_page/) which basically forces the user to be logged into Marketing Cloud in order to access the page. That will obviously only work with users configured in the account but it's an option and sometimes sufficient.